# Is a box a cylinder?

Tags: geometry, definition

My Calculus 3 professor defines a cylinder as any shape that has identical cross sections for any plane parallel to the base. He used this to explain why he refers to a box as a cylinder. This is confusing, as it muddles the differentiation of solids for me. Is this a common definition?

Comment: The definition is standard in math literature.

Comment: @JackyChong I'm only familiar with Euclid's cylinder, I'd love a reference.

Comment: @GFauxPas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_(geometry)#Related_polyhedra

Comment: Your professor is getting prisms mixed up with cylinders. Wikipedia will set him or her straight (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_(geometry), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_(geometry))

Comment: @RobArthan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_(geometry)#Other_types_of_cylinders

Comment: what are you expecting ? to show to you professor an ambigous answer ? It's a contextual definition and you will never try to buy a box by ordering a cylinder

Comment: @JackyChong: that doesn't justify the OP's professor's abuse of the term cylinder. It is **not** standard to use the term cylinder for a prism or prismatoid over an arbitrary base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In third-semester calculus, I tend to agree with Rob Arthan: Calling a solid rectangular parallelepiped a "cylinder" (or even a "rectangular cylinder") is unusual (if not rare), and nominally unfriendly to the students, even if doing so is logically defensible.

That said:

1. In differential geometry, one sometimes defines a (*generalized*) *cylinder* to be a surface comprising a family of parallel lines, one through each point of some plane curve; see for example B. O'Neill, *Elementary Differential Geometry*, second edition, p. 146. In this setting, one is careful to speak of a (*right*) *circular cylinder*.

   O'Neill also writes, "...unless the term *generalized* is used, we assume that cylinders are over *closed* curves...." That is, he really does use "cylinder" to denote surfaces with non-circular cross section.
2. If $X$ is a topological space (such as a rectangle) and $I = [0, 1]$ is the unit interval, one sometimes speaks of $I \times X$ or $X \times I$ as the "cylinder over $X$", see for example the [mapping cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_cylinder) and [suspension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_%28topology%29).