# To evaluate the given double integral

Tags: calculus

I came across this question on double integral:
Evaluate the double integral enclosed by cylinders[image]

and the planes $z$ = 0, $y$ = 4
How can those equations on the cylinders be visualized and the boundaries of integration determined?

Comment: Note that $z=x^2$ and $y=x^2$ are just the parabolae in two-dimensions, which you should be able to visualise. Then in three dimensions, you just copy these along the axis which the $z$ and $y$ does not depend on, respectively. The planes $z=0$ and $y=4$ can be treated equivalently.

Comment: Neither $z=x^2$ nor $y=x^2$ are cylinders.  They're what I usually call parabolic troughs.

Comment: @Bye_World Ok..but can you please  tell me what the x and y limits will be in this case and how?

Comment: It may or may not help, but [here's what these surfaces look like](http://imgur.com/LJiGjRu).  The bounded volume will be under the orange surface, above the green, and between the two others.  If you think about it a bit, you should be able to see what the cross sectional shapes are.  Proceed from there.

Comment: @Bye_World Almost all Calculus books call any surface whose equation is missing a variable a "generalized cylinder."  Not all cylinders are "circular cylinders."

Comment: @B.Goddard There's was just a question on this nomenclature yesterday.  And I think the consensus was that while in differential geometry and other higher level maths it's perfectly fine to talk about generalized cylinders, it should be discouraged in lower level maths like calculus.

Comment: @Bye_World  That must be a pretty narrow consensus.  I just checked the first 6 calc texts on my shelf, and they all call $y=x^2$ a cylinder in 3-space.  Wiki agrees.  MathWorld agrees.  The place where the OP got the problem agrees.  I think consensus is on my side.

Comment: @B.Goddard [Here is the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955805/is-a-box-a-cylinder/1955849#1955849) I was referencing.  I guess it was just 3 against 1 (pretty small sample size really): Jacky Chong argued that talking about generalized cylinders is fine, while igael, Rob Arthan, and Andrew D. Hwang went the other way (at least for a calculus course).  I honestly don't care -- nomenclature is pretty unimportant to me if everything is clear.  But I wanted to make sure OP knew what the surfaces where supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Refer to the image provided by @Bye_World]

From the image provided by @Bye_World you can see the image is symmetric about the x axis. So the final integral would be twice the integral on one side of the x axis.

The final limits I hope are these.

$$2*\int_{0}^{4}\int_{x^2}^{4}{x^2}.dy.dx$$
$$2*\int_{0}^{4}(x^2)\left[y\right]_{x^2}^4.dx$$